# How to mitigate the effect of Cross-Correlation between Explanatory and Dependent variables

Tags: regression, econometrics, stata, cross-correlation

I have explanatory and dependent quaterly time series variables. Seasonality was removed from both variables.

This is cross-correlogram between those two variables generated by Stata.

[image: Cross Corellogram]

I have tried to mitigate this cross-correlation by lagging the explanatory variable by 8 periods based on the highest value of cross-correlation being in the 8-the previous term.

Afterwards, I use this explanatory variable in the regression model to try and explain the dependent variable. The results for this explanatory variable are very bad in explaining the dependent variable in the regression model.

Is there a different strategy for mitigation of cross-correlation than lagging this explanatory variable by 8 terms that would provide better results in the regression model?